# $\delta = \inf f'(x) > 0 $. prove that $f(a)= 0$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R} $.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function . Suppose $\delta = \inf f'(x) > 0 $. prove that $f(a)= 0$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R} $.

I have no idea how to proceed .I would like to share one observations

For any two points $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(a)=f(b)=0$ then we would have $f'(c)= 0$ for some $c \in (a,b)$ . So $0=f'(c) \geq \inf f'(x)= \delta > 0 $. Contradiction . Hence only one such point $a$ .

Comment: Proceed by contradiction. If $f(a) \ne 0$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ then by continuity $f$ takes either only positive values, or only negative values. Suppose for instance the latter. Can you find a contradiction? Hint: use $f(x)-f(0)=\int_{0}^{x}{f'(y)dy}$ and focus on what happens when $x \to \infty$.

Comment: For sigmoid function $f(t)$ , $ f'(t) = \frac {1}{2+e^t +e^{-t} }$ . As you $ t \rightarrow \infty $  , $f'(t) \rightarrow 0 $. I  think $\delta =0$ for sigmoid $f$ . So $f$ is not a correct counterexample .

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment. I did not suggest to find a counterexample (obviously you won't find any) but to prove your result by contradiction. If you assume that $f(a) \ne 0$ for all $a$, then $f$ does not change sign. But $f(x)>f(0)+\delta x$ for $x>0$, which proves that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{f(x)}=\infty$, and $f(x)<f(0)+\delta x$ for $x<0$, which proves that $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty}{f(x)}=-\infty$. Hence $f$ must change sign, which is a contradiction. Thus the postulate that $f(a) \ne 0$ for all $a$ is wrong, which proves the result.

Comment: @ Oliv  Some other fellow commented after you saying that he/she has found a counter-example . He/she  argued that $f(x)= \frac {1}{(1+e^{-x})} $ would provide for an counter-example to the asked question . My first comment was to reason him/her that his example would not work . Hence was the first comment .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(0) = 0$ there is nothing to show. Otherwise let $a \in \mathbb R$ be nonzero. According to the mean-value theorem there exists $c$ in between $a$ and $0$ satisfying $$\frac{f(a) - f(0)}{a - 0} = f'(c) > \delta.$$

Assume first that $f(0) < 0$. Then for each $a > 0$ the above observation implies $f(a) > f(0) + a \delta$, and by taking $a$ sufficiently large you get $f(a) > 0$. Now apply the intermediate value theorem.

If $f(0) < 0$ take negative values of $a$ instead.

Comment: Thanks ! Great answer .  I would also like to know if the observation i made in the question is correct or not ? Can you help me out ?

Comment: Looks good. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

If
$d = \inf f'(x) > 0
$,
then
$f'(x) \ge d$
for all $x$.

Suppose $f(a) > 0$
for some $a$.
Then
$f(a)-f(a-x)
=\int_{a-x}^a f(t) dt
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
f(a-x)
&=f(a)-\int_{a-x}^a f'(t) dt\\
&\lt f(a)-\int_{a-x}^a d dt\\
&= f(a)-d(a-(a-x))\\
&= f(a)-dx\\
&=0
\text{ for } x = \frac{f(a)}{d}
\end{array}
$

Since $f$ is continuous,
$f(z) = 0$
for some
$a-\frac{f(a)}{d}
< z < a
$.

Similarly,
if $f(a) < 0$
for some $a$,
Then
$f(a+x)-f(a)
=\int_{a}^{a+x} f(t) dt
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
f(a+x)
&=f(a)+\int_{a}^{a+x} f'(t) dt\\
&\gt f(a)+\int_{a}^{a+x} d dt\\
&= f(a)+dx\\
&=0
\text{ for } x = \frac{-f(a)}{d}
\end{array}
$

Since $f$ is continuous,
$f(z) = 0$
for some
$a 
< z
<a-\frac{f(a)}{d}
$.